# Formatting a CSS property in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Please can someone tell me how to format the marginLeft value? I can't figure out how to escape the dash when declaring properties in this way. I have tried quite a few different ways but none have worked. Please also let me know if it is not possible at all. Thanks.

```
import React from "react";

const informationStyle = { 
  fontSize: "0.6rem",
  marginLeft: "get-spacing(small)"
};

const Information = () => (
   <span style={informationStyle}>
      <svg className="cp-icon-svg cp-icon-circle" /></svg>
   </span>
);

export default Information;
```

Comment: what is get-spacing(small) in mraginLeft

Comment: it comes from a sass spacing map

Comment: You need to make a class in sass and use className ratherThan use style

Comment: here a template to use sass with react https://github.com/bsmahala/react-redux-route-sass-login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use Sass in the React component? I don't believe that's possible. What you could do is simply put the Sass inside a separate Sass file, compile that into css, and then import the css into your project.

```
import './yourCssFile.css'; // Put this below your React import

const Information = () => (
   <span className="informationStyle"> // informationStyle is inside yourCssFile
      <svg className="cp-icon-svg cp-icon-circle" /></svg>
   </span>
);
```

You could also use Css modules rather than importing the full Css file. You can learn more about Css modules [here](https://medium.com/@pioul/modular-css-with-react-61638ae9ea3e).